# Why is reloadData in IOS tutorial unnecessary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

While doing the ios tutorial ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html ), i found out that this step

> 7. Reload the data in your table.
>
> Because the table view doesn’t keep
>   track of its data, it’s the responsibility of the data source—in this
>   case, your table view controller—to notify the table view when there’s
>   new data for it to display.
>
> `[self.tableView reloadData];`

is not necessary : the new item is added to the tableview even without this code fragment. Any idea why ?

Comment: Your controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController` ?

Comment: Yes, it is a subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: Say your user clicks a cell on the Table View Controller which ultimately leads to a screen which causes another table view item being created. When they return to original Table View Controller, it will have no way of knowing that's its cached data is incorrect. By putting reLoadData in ViewDidLoad you are telling the VC its cached data is now out of date.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is the superclass, `UITableViewController`, offering you a quiet helping hand and calling `reloadData` when it is told that its view (the table view) is displayed (I think that is the only time it helps out like this, can't say I've checked if it calls `reloadData` if you have already done it when the view is created).

If you were using `UIViewController` as the superclass and adding your own property to the table view and implementing the table delegate and data source methods then this wouldn't happen and you would need to explicitly call `reloadData` to get anything to be shown in the view.

Comment: in fact, after testing, in doesn't reload all the data, just add the new line to the tableview without touching the other line. It seems like the UITableViewControler at display check the number of line, then call the cell constructors only for the new line. It's more efficient that reloading all data.